# Copy and rename a file with mule

Tags: file, ftp, copy, mule

I'm trying to set up a mule app that consists of two flows.

One that retreives files from an ftp to local folder.
The other one polling the same folder and uploads the file to another FTP-server and also copies
a file from a another local folder, renames the copied file to the same filename as the "FTP-file" but with another extension and also uploads it to the same FTP-server.

I've tried to set a variable with the incomming filename  but I don't know how to
copy a templatefile and rename it from a local folder as in the flow below.

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the `outputPattern` property on the file endpoint using the variable name.

Comment: I can'tget this working. What I want to do is to have a file in a template folder and when a file appears in the flow this file is transfered to the output FTP-server together with the file in the template folder renamed to the incoming file's filename but with a new extension. How to trigger the copy by the incoming file transfer?

Comment: In that case don't use the file endpoint, write a java component to get the file contents  + delete the file and pass to the FTP

Answer (score 0):

The file endpoint has the attribute to serve this purpose.

```
<file:outbound-endpoint path="${destination_path}"  outputPattern="[new filename to be given to the file ]"  doc:name="File" >
</file:outbound-endpoint>
```

on a FTP endpoint also the outputPattern attribute  can be set to the desired filename.

```
<ftp:outbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="21" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP" outputPattern="test.xml"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for you post but I think I need some more help. WHat I'd like to do is to trig a copy and rename a templatefile from a folder when a file enters the flow so this copied file can be uploade together with the incomming file to a FTP server. If the incoming file is [TEST112211.xml] the files transfered to the FTP server should be [TEST112211.xml] and [TEST112211.imp]. The imp file is an import directive to the service reading the xml-file.

Comment: For the problem you have mentioned in the comment, a custom transformer should serve the purpose. You can have a custom transformer to read file from the template folder and then it should be written onto the FTP folder by an ftp outbound. This flow of Custom trasnformer and FTP should be called from your main flow which is reading the main file.